# Firebase Realtime Database reading don't work

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
class OverviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        view.button.setOnClickListener {
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
            databaseReference.child(auth!!.uid!!).get().addOnSuccessListener {

                if (it.exists()) {

                    val name = it.child("name").value
                    view.textView_name.text = name.toString()

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Nothing found")
                }

            }
        }




        return view

    }

}
```

My database has a Reference named "Users" and below that a child with the userID where the values are saved. And he said to me that it dosen't exists but it do.

Comment: "he said to me that it dosen't exists but it do." What does that mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean that it exists in the Firebase Console?

Comment: It exists in the realtime database